# Get deleted values from 3 tables and put in 1 table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, triggers

I have three tables [image: This is the database model]

The end-user can select a top2000jaar from a dropdownlist in ASP, which will has its value send to an stored procedure, the stored procedure has to delete all the values in [LIJST] where top2000jaar equals the value that has been selected but a trigger is needed which delete the row where song.songid = lijst.songid from [SONG] when that songid doesnt exist in [LIJST] anymore, and therefore if an artist in [artiest] has no more songs left in [song], the artist should be deleted too.

All that deleted data should be then put in [logtable]

[image: sample data]

I have tried a way which i thought would work, but didnt.

Expected output should be this:

[image] <- 31-dec-13 is a typo, it is 2013

This is the trigger is created, with some answers i found on google, but not working:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGremoveSong]
ON [dbo].[Lijst]
AFTER DELETE AS

Begin
DELETE FROM song where songid not in (Select songid from lijst)
END
begin
INSERT INTO logtable
   SELECT 
       *
   FROM deleted
 end
```

Comment: please add your structure, sample data and expected output in the question itself by editing the question. please do not add links. question can become unanswerable if the links become broken in future.

Comment: Please add You triggers code too! And what was the problem with the code.

Comment: Are you just struggling to update the logtable or with deleting from the other tables too?

Comment: both, i am half a year in my study, wich now contains some harder sql, but for some projects i just can not think how to put it together, i know how to delete them seperately though, but how to trigger it so it is all automated i have no clue

Comment: your trigger looks correct, however it only deals with deletes to `Lijst` table. just add similar trigger for `Song` and `Artiest`. the trigger on `Artiest` table doesn't need a `DELETE`, only an `INSERT INTO logtable  SELECT * FROM deleted`

Comment: thanks, i will take a shot at your answer this afternoon. Ill check in with you later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using this as your trigger should do the job, this will only populate what has actually been deleted so if artiest has not been deleted it will show as null next to the song etc.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGremoveSong]
ON [dbo].[Lijst]
AFTER DELETE AS

Begin
   INSERT INTO logtable
   SELECT  sng.titel, art.naam, sng.jaar, positie, top2000jaar
   FROM deleted d
   Outer Apply
   (Select titel, jaar, artiestid from song where not exists (Select * from lijst where songid = d.songid) and songid = d.songid) sng
   Outer Apply
   (Select naam from artiest where not exists (Select * from song where artiestid = sng.artiestid and songid <> d.songid) and artiestid = sng.artiestid) art

DELETE FROM song s where not exists (Select * from lijst where songid = s.songid)
DELETE FROM artiest a where not exists (Select * from song where artiestid = a.artiestid)
End
```

Here is an example SQLFiddle where song 9 is deleted and it's the last song for that artist: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4405b/1/0

The following will show all fields on deletion:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRGremoveSong]
ON [dbo].[Lijst]
AFTER DELETE AS

Begin
   INSERT INTO logtable
   SELECT  sng.titel, art.naam, sng.jaar, positie, top2000jaar
   FROM deleted d
   Outer Apply
   (Select titel, jaar, artiestid from song where songid = d.songid) sng
   Outer Apply
   (Select naam from artiest where artiestid = sng.artiestid) art

DELETE FROM song s where not exists (Select * from lijst where songid = s.songid)
DELETE FROM artiest a where not exists (Select * from song where artiestid = a.artiestid)
End
```

Here is the SQLFiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd6171/1/0

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the late response, you trigger looks spot on, but i get an awfull lot of null values in my logtable. Not on all rows though. This is part of my output: http://puu.sh/ilyxQ/3d68185e3a.png

This is my trigger: http://puu.sh/ilyCb/d3d765deeb.png

Comment: You will get nulls if it wasn't the last song delete. So if you have a list of 3 songs to 1 artist and 1 of the songs is repeated 2 times in lijst table, when you delete 1 song 1 time in lijst it won't delete the song in the song table nor the artiest in the artiest table. It will still log this though but fields relevant to the song and artiest tables will populate with null. Only when deleting all occurances of the song in lijst which deletes the last song for the artiest in the song table which causes the artiest to be deleted on the artiest table will you see all fields populated

Comment: Okay, how Can i always populate the fields, because thats my intention. The deletion is right though, where i thank you for

Comment: I'll get you an update on the code so it can do that, bare with me

Comment: @MaartenHeebink The bottom code in my answer is what you're looking for. I've left the top in to help anyone else that may be looking for a similar solution or in case you change your mind on how you want it to work.

Comment: thanks for the help, but with your new trigger, i miss a awfull lot of rows in the logtable, with your old trigger it would log 2000 rows (wich is the correct number) with an huge amount of null's (wich i all wanted to fil up) but with your new one i get 136( wich should be 2000) with no nulls  (which is great).

Comment: Seems a bit strange but sounds like there are cases where there maybe isn't an artiest or songid matching. If you try the updated does it give you any better results? It will put nulls in areas where it finds no match.

Comment: Nope, outputs just 136 rows, pretty strange though.

Comment: Damn, this is gonna sound bad, my colleague did a whole lot of deletion and adding on the same tables, without my knowledge. I guess that is whats also screwing up your triggers. Whole identity seed got screwed up in the process. Gonna fix it and come back to you!

Comment: Logging in for almost a year ago. Realised i didn't credit you, as this worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the logic to the stored procedure to do all of that, something like this:

```
DECLARE @LIJSTID_TO_DELETE INT = 123
DECLARE @SongID INT
DECLARE @ArtistID INT

-- SET the songid for the row you're going to delete
SELECT @SongID = songid 
FROM LIJST 
WHERE top2000jaar = @LIJSTID_TO_DELETE

-- first deletion
DELETE FROM LIJST 
WHERE top2000jaar = @LIJSTID_TO_DELETE

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    INSERT INTO LOGTABLE.... -- deleted LIJST values

-- set the artist id for the song you are going to delete
SELECT @ArtistID = artiestid
FROM Song 
WHERE songid = @SongID

-- delete the linked song (could use cascade delete if required)
DELETE FROM Song
WHERE songid = @SongID

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    INSERT INTO LOGTABLE.... -- deleted song values

-- Delete the artist if their songs no longer exist
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Song WHERE artiestid = ArtistID )
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Artiest
    WHERE artiestid = @ArtistID 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        INSERT INTO LOGTABLE.... -- deleted artiest values
END
```

`@@ROWCOUNT` simply returns the number of rows affected by the previous statement, so it will only log if a row is deleted.